# OAuth in PlayReady License Retrieval in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, drm, playready

Any idea how to inject OAuth headers into PlayReadyLicenseAcquisitionServiceRequest so they are included with the BeginServiceRequest()?  I can't leverage the license URL's query string, or embed the OAuth token in the body; it has to be in the header of the License retrieval's http request.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of OAuth you are using?

Comment: @MikeMa.  It's OAuth 1.0, and I have the header already prepared but I just can't figure out how to inject it into the license request.  Unless there's a whole different approach to OAuth I'm missing..

Answer (score 0):

I found some great sample code here:

https://www.eyecatch.no/blog/using-playready-and-smooth-streaming-in-a-windows-10-uwp-app/

but this was the magic sauce below (with my header addition):

```
    public static async Task<bool> RequestLicenseManual(PlayReadyLicenseAcquisitionServiceRequest request, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] headers)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ProtectionManager PlayReady Manual License Request in progress");

        try
        {
            var r = request.GenerateManualEnablingChallenge();

            var content = new ByteArrayContent(r.GetMessageBody());

            foreach (var header in r.MessageHeaders.Where(x => x.Value != null))
            {
                if (header.Key.Equals("Content-Type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(header.Value.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    content.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, r.Uri) { Content = content };

            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                msg.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value.ToString());
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Requesting license from {0} with custom data {1}", msg.RequestUri, await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.SendAsync(msg);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                request.ProcessManualEnablingResponse(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ProtectionManager PlayReady License Request failed: " + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ProtectionManager PlayReady License Request failed: " + ex.Message);

            return false;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("ProtectionManager PlayReady License Request successfull");

        return true;
    }
```